# PostgreSQL - Constraint on each custom type element in an array

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have this custom type:

```
CREATE TYPE post AS (
  title varchar(100),
  content varchar(10000)
);
```

And this table:

```
CREATE TABLE blogs (
  -- Constraint on one custom type element:
  one_post post NOT NULL
    CHECK ((one_post).title IS NOT NULL AND (one_post).content IS NOT NULL),

  -- Constraint on array elements:
  posts post[] NOT NULL CHECK (???)
);
```

As commented in the code, I want to check that the title and content of each element of `posts` are `NOT NULL`, but I can't find a way to express that. What is the right way to do this?

(P.S.: I know the right way is to normalize my schema, I'm just curious if what I asked can be done.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For complex check constraints usually used stored functions.

There is my attempt to make it in convenient way:

First of all:

```
create type post as (
  title varchar(100),
  content varchar(10000)
);

create function is_filled(post) returns bool immutable language sql as $$
  select $1.title is not null and $1.content is not null
$$;

with t(x) as (values(('a','b')::post), (('a',null)::post), ((null,null)::post))
select *, is_filled(x), (x).is_filled from t;
```

```
╔═══════╤═══════════╤═══════════╗
║   x   │ is_filled │ is_filled ║
╠═══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╣
║ (a,b) │ t         │ t         ║
║ (a,)  │ f         │ f         ║
║ (,)   │ f         │ f         ║
╚═══════╧═══════════╧═══════════╝
```

Here you can see two syntaxes of function calling (personally I like the second one - it is more OOP-like)

Next:

```
create function is_filled(post[]) returns bool immutable language sql as $$
  select bool_and((x).is_filled) and $1 is not null from unnest($1) as x
$$;

with t(x) as (values(('a','b')::post), (('a',null)::post), ((null,null)::post))
select (array_agg(x)).is_filled from t;
```

```
╔═══════════╗
║ is_filled ║
╠═══════════╣
║ f         ║
╚═══════════╝
```

Note that we are able to use functions with same name but with different parameters - it is Ok in PostgreSQL.

Finally:

```
create table blogs (
  one_post post check ((one_post).is_filled),
  posts post[] check ((posts).is_filled)
);

insert into blogs values(('a','b'), array[('a','b'),('c','d')]::post[]); -- Works
insert into blogs values(('a','b'), array[('a','b'),(null,'d')]::post[]); -- Fail
insert into blogs values(('a',null), array[('a','b')]::post[]); -- Fail
```

PS: script to clear our experiment:

```
/*
drop table if exists blogs;
drop function if exists is_filled(post);
drop function if exists is_filled(post[]);
drop type if exists post;
*/
```

Comment: Thanks! Very elegant solution.